# How to create rating system in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, rating-system

I'm doing one litle project with JSP for topic Library. I want to create a rating system for books in library when end-user view detail of book and rating for this book. Can anyone give hints or tutorials how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the [jQuery Star Rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) for this. Check the [demo page](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing) how it all look like. The JSP/HTML basically look like this (you only need to put the necessary JS/CSS/image files in the public webcontent). The magic is done by giving the radio buttons the class name `star`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Star rating demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.rating.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.rating.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="star">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="star">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="star">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="star">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="star">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the server side you just use [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain the rating value.

```
String rating = request.getParameter("rating");
// ...
```

With the above example, it'll return 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Comment: is this code still valid? star1.length always returns 1 for me.